# jquery $.ajax .done .fail giving unexpected behaviour

Tags: jquery, ajax, behavior

The following code is giving me an unexpected behavior. When the dataType in the ajax call is json it returns an error as it should in this case and executes the .fail path. The line `$("#greetingsBlock" ).html(stuff.responseText);` executes correctly and populates the `<div th:fragment="greetingsList"  class="results-block">` in the results.html correctly with the updated html.

However reading another link I removed the `dataType: "json",` from the ajax call to fix the fail problem and the return is correctly mapped to `.done(function( stuff )`. The odd thing is that the line `$("#greetingsBlock").html(stuff.responseText );` does not update the html even though the `stuff.responseText` is the same as in the .fail case. I checked both cases in the debugger. The controller method being called is the same in both cases and returns with no problem. I am a bit stumped on this one.

I am using jquery 1.9.2, Thymeleaf, and Spring MVC in my appication

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    headers: { 
         'Accept': 'application/json', 
         'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
          },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data : data,
    url: url
})
  .done(function( stuff ) {
      $("#greetingsBlock").html(stuff.responseText );
  })
    .fail(function(stuff) {
      $("#greetingsBlock" ).html(stuff.responseText);
  });
```

results.html

```
<div th:fragment="greetingsList"  class="results-block">
    <h3>Greetings list</h3>
    <form id="toDelete" th:object="${greetingWrapper}" method="post">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Delete?</th>0
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Date Created   </th>
          </tr>

          <tr th:each="greeting, rowStat : *{greetings}" th:class="${rowStat.odd}? 'odd'">
            <td><input type="checkbox" th:checked="${greeting.delete}" th:field="*{greetings[__${rowStat.index}__].delete}" name="delete"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{greetings[__${rowStat.index}__].id}" name="id" readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{greetings[__${rowStat.index}__].content}" name="content" readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{greetings[__${rowStat.index}__].dateCreated}" name="dateCreated" readonly="readonly" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <button id="deleteGreetings" name="deleteGreetings" 
            th:onclick="'javascript:deleteTheGreetings()'" type="button" >Delete Greeting(s)</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: ARGGG - just stumbled upon a fix. This code works, I have no idea why however. Seems that in one case "stuff" is enough and the other requires "stuff.responseText"   '.done(function( stuff ) {
      $("#greetingsBlock").html(stuff );'

Comment: then post it as an answer below so if others stumble upon a similar error, they can fix it as well :)

Comment: `.fail()` is fired when you can't reach the host or other problems... It doesn't return a json encode from your server. That's why.

Answer (score 0):

ARGGG - just stumbled upon a fix. This code works, I have no idea why however. Seems that in one case "stuff" is enough and the other requires "stuff.responseText" '.done(function( stuff ) { $("#greetingsBlock").html(stuff );'